# LaTeX Worshop for VS Code doesn't work: "Latexmk: Wildcards in file names didn't match any files"

Tags: latexmk, visual-studio-code

I tried to start using Visual Studio Code as a LaTeX editor for Windows following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDSpXN6AZAo) tutorial.

I completed all the steps: installed VS Code with a LaTeX Workshop extension, installed MikTeX and also Perl (don't get why do I need that though). Finally I tried to build a simple project:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    $$
    e^{i \varphi} = \cos\varphi + i \sin\varphi.
    $$
\end{document}
```

However, I got this strange error message:

```
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)
Win CP console initial and current in/out Win: (437, 65001), (1252, 1252)
Coding system for system and terminal: 'CP1252'
---
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Mar. 2022. Version 4.77, version: 4.77.

Latexmk: Wildcards in file names didn't match any files
Use
   latexmk -help
to get usage information
```

So, what do I do to get it work?

Edit:
There is also some debug output of LaTeX Workshop (the one above is labeled as the LaTeX Compiler one):

```
Recipe returns with error: 10/null. PID: 10668. message: Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)
```

I don't know if it helps.

Comment: How **exactly** is your configuration for VS code? Additionally, please don't use `$$...$$` that is not LaTeX.

Comment: @daleif what do you mean by configuration for VS Code? If you want to see some kind of configuration file, please, tell me where can I find it.

Comment: You have somehow configured VS code to use `latexmk`. I don't use VS Code so I cannot tell you where to look.

Comment: @daleif well, I didn't do anything specific. Just installed the extension (LaTeX Workshop, as mentioned earlier) and MikTeX and let it go. It prompted me to install the `latexmk` -- I proceeded -- and that's where all the problems begin. I tried to find any kind of configuration file for VS Code or the extension but didn't succeed.

Comment: @AndreyDmitrenko did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem :/

Comment: @IridescenceDeep unfortunatelly, no. I gave up and just moved to TexStudio which didn't cause any troubles yet.

Answer (score 0):

Path to you TeX file must contain ONLY English characters, spaces, dashes and underscores. Otherwise you will get this error every time

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The OP said that using another application (TeXStudio) worked well, so it is unclear whether this is really the solution to the problem (but it might well be part of it).